# What is the function of "-I" in Makefile?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

I am installing a software (Ubantu system) by simply going to the download folder and typing:`make`.

In the Makefile, there is a line:

```
SW=-I /usr/include/python2.7/ -I ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/
```

When I

```
ls ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/
```

I don't have it in my system.

(1) What is the function of this line?

(2) Since I don't have the second file, should I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The purpose of that line is indicating the compiler additional directories where to look for header files. Check [[GNU.GCC]: Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.4/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)
2. If you need to access *NumPy* *API*s, you should indeed modify it to your *NumPy* installation *include dir*. If it isn't installed, install it using `python -m pip install numpy` (also available for download at [[PyPI]: numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy)***<sup>(1)</sup>***). 
   If it's just a leftover (copy / paste), and the compiler doesn't complain about not finding (*NumPy* related) *.h* files, simply remove it

---

#### Footnotes

- ***#1***: Your paths indicate *Python **2.7***. That's out of support. Switch to *Python **3***, as some packages might no longer be available (for example, *NumPy* doesn't have the newer versions built for *Python 2.7*)
- Also, the typical command for installing software is `make install`